# How to upload file to artifactory generic repository with gradle?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I build app distribution with gradle, which a tar file contains everything needed. I created a generic repository in artifactory. I want to upload the tarball to the generic repository.

By looking up this documentation 
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

I didn't find a way to do so. 
I am a new gradle and artifactory user, can anyone give me guide.

```
task uploadDistroTar(type: org._10ne.gradle.rest.RestTask) {
    httpMethod = 'PUT'
    uri = 'http://x.x.x.x:8081/artifactory/repo/foo.tar'
    username = 'admin'
    password = 'passwd'
    requestContentType = groovyx.net.http.ContentType.BINARY
    requestBody = new File("build/distributions/foo.tar").bytes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use the [Gradle REST plugin](https://github.com/noamt/rest-gradle-plugin). Just use the PUT request to upload the file to the repository you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I use the following task to upload a tar file
It fails because of security reason, in artifactory log it shows
    2015-08-27 12:11:03,928 [DENIED DEPLOY] repo:/foo.tar for anonymous/x.x.x.x

It did not use the username I provided, but use anonymous user. If I give anonymous use rights to put files, then I can upload the tar file successfully. But I want only some register user to be able to upload files.

I have amended the task file to the question

Comment: That's the time to summon @noamt, the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

More modern solution is to use [Artifactory Java Client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java):

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
    .setUrl("ArtifactoryUrl")
    .setUsername("username")
    .setPassword("password")
    .build();

java.io.File file = new java.io.File("fileToUpload.txt");
File result = artifactory.repository("RepoName").upload("path/to/newName.txt", file).doUpload();
```

Comment: using latest 2.5.1 of Artifactory Java Client I always receive a:
{code}
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
*** cut ***
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:226)
{code} - does anyone have a idea why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution by read the plugin's source code,
just set:

```
preemptiveAuth = true
```